# Looking for an elegy poem about a flower the narrator cared for (at the cost of enjoying life), which died and left him devastated

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I'm looking for an elegy-style poem in which the narrator recounts ignoring the beautiful flowers around them, instead attending to a single flower that had yet to bloom. They thought this one flower would grow to become more spectacular than the rest, but it instead shriveled and died, causing the narrator great dismay.

I can't recall the exact format, but it was most likely a prose poem of a couple hundred words. The style seemed to be of European origin in the 19th or 20th century. I read this a couple weeks ago on a literature exam; the question that used this passage was scheduled to be released, but has not been to the best of my knowledge.

Some poems I ruled out are "Elegy Written in a Country Churchyard", "Elegy IX: The Autumnal", and "Elegy Before Death". I've tried searching for various combinations of "elegy", "flower", "eulogy", etc. to no avail. I've tried everywhere I could think of, but this particular piece eludes me. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Can you give an approximate time period when you would have read this poem? Was it published alongside other poems (e.g. in a collection?) See the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for more kinds of useful information you could [edit] into your question. Every bit may help those trying to identify the poem.

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the question with some more information that might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Was this the AP Literature exam, by any chance? If so, I took it too, though it seems I got a different form, as I don't remember this poem

Comment: It was, although I'm not sure if the FRQs from the one I got were posted in the same place as the others ... I also considered the possibility that the piece was written specifically for that exam, though this seemed pretty unlikely.

Comment: If no one can find the poem, waiting long enough and then asking your Literature teacher may work - College Board [released the  2020 online-exam questions](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/ap-english-literature-and-composition/exam/past-exam-questions?course=ap-english-literature-and-composition#apricot_LxTtah2mgw) into the [AP Classroom Question Bank](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/instructional-resources/ap-classroom), a free database which is searchable by teachers.

Comment: Good point - I could only find [this PDF](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/pdf/ap21-frq-english-literature.pdf) from College Board for this year. If all else fails, I'll make a note to ask.